# Convergence in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I want to make a statement about the following sequence of functions whether it converges in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ (space of distributions):
\begin{align}
\phi_n(x) = e^{-x^2/n^2}.
\end{align}
I want to do it as analytical as possible.

The definition is clear but I do not see how to applicate it to our problem:

$T_n \rightarrow T$ in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ if $T_n(f) \rightarrow T(f)$ for all $f \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$.

Is there anyone who can help me :)

Comment: $\phi = 1$ uniformly?

Comment: Can you find a function $\phi$ such that $\phi_n$ converges to it ? Pointwise or uniformly ? What about $\phi_n'$ ? What can you say then about say $\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\phi_n(x)-\phi(x)) \varphi(x)dx, \varphi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$  (without any complicated theorem) ?

Comment: the convergence is uniform on $[-A,A]$ but not on $\mathbb{R}$ (very different)

Comment: sorry, but I do not know what to do next...

Comment: Come on.. If $\varphi$ is supported on $[-a,a]$ then $T_n(\varphi) = \int_{-a}^a \phi_n(x)\varphi(x)dx=\int_{-a}^a \phi(x)\varphi(x)dx+\int_a^b(\phi_n(x)-\phi(x)\varphi(x)dx$ and since for $n > \sqrt{2a}$ : $|\phi_n(x)-\phi(x)| < \frac{2x^2}{n^2}$ you get $|\int_{-a}^a(\phi_n(x)-\phi(x)\varphi(x)dx| < \frac{1}{n^2}\int_{-a}^a  |x^2\varphi(x)|dx$

Comment: sorry, but I do not see the reason not to use DCT... with DTC it is much easier

Answer (score 2):

For any $f \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$
$$
\langle\phi_n,f\rangle=\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-x^2/n^2}\,f(x)\,dx.
$$
Use the dominated convergence theorem to show that the integral converges as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I think it is better to avoid the DCT here

Comment: @user1952009: why?

Comment: @tubmaster Because you will understand better with bounding $\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\phi_n(x)-\phi(x)) \varphi(x)dx$ by something $\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. For example, try using that $|e^y-1| < 2 y$ for $|y < 1/2|$

Comment: another try here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185983/convergence-of-a-sequence-of-functions-in-mathcald-mathbbr

Comment: My try is as following:

\begin{align}
T_n(f) = \int_\mathbb{R}e^{-x^2/n^2} f(x) dx
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} T_n(f) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_\mathbb{R}e^{-x^2/n^2} f(x) dx = \int_\mathbb{R} \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{-x^2/n^2} f(x) dx = \int_\mathbb{R} 1\cdot f(x) dx < \infty
\end{align}
where I used DCT.
Would that be enough to show convergence in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$? It converges against $1$.$$ $$

Comment: Yes, that is enough. $e^{-x^2/n^2}$ convenes in the sense of distributions to the constant function $1$.